# Adding Image To UIImageView In Separate Class

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I have two view controllers: Products View Controller and Detail View Controller.
When the user taps a cell on a UITableView, it will transition to the Detail View Controller. The Detail View Controller has a UIImageView in it names imageEq. I'm trying to set the image in the Products View Controller. This is how I'm doing it:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"])
    {
        DetailViewController *dvc;
        UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HorseImage.png"];
        [dvc.imageEq setImage:pic];
        NSLog(@"Pic should be set");
}
........ (non relevant code)
}
```

I connected the outlets, copied the image into the project, and made sure all my spelling is correct. When I run this, the image view remains blank and has never loaded the image. I can't figure out why not, this all looks perfect to me. Does the above code look flawed in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your DetailViewController pointer to this code below, it should work for you.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"])
    {
        UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HorseImage.png"];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailImage:pic];

        NSLog(@"Pic should be set");
}
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks Jim.

**EDIT**

Add the following property in your DetailViewController's header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *detailImage;
```

And in the viewDidLoad of your DetailViewController's .m file, add the following

```
self.imageEq.image = _detailImage;
```

I hope this updated answer help.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. However, when I try this I get the warning "incompatible pointer types sending 'uiimage' to parameter of type 'uiimageview'", I'm unsure of how to solve that.

Comment: This code will set a UIImage, though I take it the imageEq is a UIImageView. I'll add some code for you to put into your header file  of your DetailViewController and this will sort it, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Also change

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setImageEq:pic];
```

to

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setImageEq:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic]];
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the image is still blank after making the changes, I double checked and the outlet is connected, no typos, and the image is imported.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", [segue destinationViewController]);` to check that [segue destinationViewController] is initialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the NSLog read back was "<DetailViewController: 0x8b43280>" so it appears to have. Also, for `setImageEq`, the UIImageView is named `imageEq`, would the capitalization of i matter in that case?

Comment: It is good that DetailViewController is created. Capitalization does not matter here. Are you sure your DetailViewController is pushed/shown?